# Merge dict in a Python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Assume I have this:

```
[
    {"name": "bob", "total": 1},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 5},
    {"name": "eve", "total": 2},
    {"name": "bob", "total": 3},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
]
```

I want to transform this list into :

```
[
    {"name": "bob", "total": 4},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 9},
    {"name": "eve", "total": 2}
]
```

For now, I walk through the whole second list to find if the key exist for each loop of the first list.

How can I achieve this with a lower complexity?

Comment: Could you show your current code, please? You can do this in O(n) by using a dict that maps key names to value totals. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8528952/6243352)

Comment: great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [
    {"name": "bob", "total": 1},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 5},
    {"name": "eve", "total": 2},
    {"name": "bob", "total": 3},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
]

# calculate the frequency of each key
freq = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for d in a:
    freq[d['name']] += d['total']

# build the result list
a = list()
for key, val in freq.items():
    a.append({'name': key, 'total': val})
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two pieces of information (name and total), I would suggest changing your schema a bit. Instead of a list of dictionaries, use a single dictionary where the keys are names and the values are totals:

```py
>>> values = [
...     {"name": "bob", "total": 1},
...     {"name": "alice", "total": 5},
...     {"name": "eve", "total": 2},
...     {"name": "bob", "total": 3},
...     {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
...     {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
... ]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> totals_by_name = defaultdict(int)
>>> for value in values:
...     totals_by_name[value["name"]] += value["total"]
... 
>>> totals_by_name
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'bob': 4, 'alice': 9, 'eve': 2})
```

This can work even if you have more pieces of data that you want to look up by name (replace the integer value with a nested dictionary that stores the total as well as other data).

Comment: Yes it's better to clean the schema. But as it's an API output I can't change the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` from the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# itemgetter(foo) is roughly equivalent to lambda x: x[foo]
get_name = itemgetter('name')
get_total = itemgetter('total')

lst = [
    {"name": "bob", "total": 1},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 5},
    {"name": "eve", "total": 2},
    {"name": "bob", "total": 3},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
]
grouped = groupby(sorted(lst, key=get_name), get_name)
new_list = [{'name': k, 'total': sum(get_total(x) for x in v)} for k, v in grouped]
```

`groupby` will produce a new sequence that collects the dicts from the original list into subsequences, based on a common value of the `'name'` attribute. Iterating over that lets you extract all the `total` values to sum up for use in a new list of `dict` values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say,

```
your_data = [
    {"name": "bob", "total": 1},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 5},
    {"name": "eve", "total": 2},
    {"name": "bob", "total": 3},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
    {"name": "alice", "total": 2},
]
```

You can simply use **pandas** to receive the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)    
df = df.groupby(by = 'name', as_index = False).sum('total')
result = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

**OUTPUT**: [{'name': 'alice', 'total': 9}, {'name': 'bob', 'total': 4}, {'name': 'eve', 'total': 2}]